# Adding Python login function into a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops

How to add the login function into the loop so it would look like I described in the `expected output` part.

the code workflow looks like the following:

- login into account 1
- Do stuff for every item in the range
- logout

And then repeat it for the next account.

This process should loop until there are no more items in the range. So after the 3rd account, it should continue again with the first account.

**code:**

```
import time

def login(username):
    print("login", username)

def logout():
    print("logout")

N = 4
def worker():
    log = []
    for idx, Item in enumerate(range(1, 17)):
        if idx % N == 0:
            print("Done Session") 
            time.sleep(1)
            log.append(logout())
        try: 
            #Do Stuff           
            print(Item) 
        except:
            pass
    return log

def main():
    login("user1")
    worker()
    login("user2")
    worker()
    login("user3")
    worker()

main()
```

**output:**

```
login user1
Done Session
logout
1
2
3
4
Done Session
logout
5
6
7
8
Done Session
logout
```

**expected output:**

```
login user1 
Done session
logout 
login user2
1
2
3
4
Done seassion 
logout
login user3
5
6
7
8
Done seassion 
logout
login user4
...
```

Comment: Do you need the numbers? Do you plan to exchange them later?

Comment: @Atlas435 Yes, each number represents a username from a textfile. wouldn't really change that much

Comment: So you need {'user1': [1,2,3,4], 'user2': [5,6,7,8]...}
You can use a dictionary for it or not?

Comment: You have a seperate textfile for each user?

Comment: But the accounts should loop multiple numbers, as I wrote in my question. The accounts would switch until there are no more numbers.

Comment: So each account have multiple usernames. right?

Comment: I was thinking something like make tasks a generator, and use "for item in itertools.islice(tasks, N):" with lazy evaluation of the login/logout, as those may be relatively expensive.

Comment: It might be smarter to have separate functions for each worker session and the actual do-stuff for one worker. But that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: using `range(1, 17) inside `worker` make no sens - you should use it outside `worker` and send value(s) to worker - ie.  `worker(start, end)` - and inside worker use them - ie, `range(start, end)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you would like to suspend the execution of the `worker` function and continue it after another user login is executed. If so, you can turn your `worker` function into generator, using [yiled](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) operator when it should return control to the `main` function. Then you can create this iterator and use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) function to iterate over `worker`:

```py
import time

def login(username):
    print("login", username)

def logout():
    print("logout")

N = 4
def worker():
    log = []
    for idx, Item in enumerate(range(1, 17)):
        if idx % N == 0:
            print("Done Session") 
            time.sleep(1)
            log.append(logout())
            yield
        try: 
            #Do Stuff           
            print(Item) 
        except:
            pass
    return log

def main():
    do_tasks = worker()
    login("user1")
    next(do_tasks)
    login("user2")
    next(do_tasks)
    login("user3")
    next(do_tasks)

main()
```

Comment: I'd consider skipping the logout where N == 0

Comment: @KennyOstrom What do you mean by skipping? I need to logout before I can login into something.

Comment: Is there a way to instantly start with the first 4 items?. Because currently it only starts after one login/logout process.

Comment: @keyz_, you can rewrite done session condition so it wouldn't  be `True` when idx is zero, looks like this is what @kenny-ostrom offered: `if (idx % N == 0) and (idx != 0):`

Comment: Ahh ye now I got that. Had an other solution writing the done session condition below the try part and doing it like `if idx % N == (N-1):`